# Different gradient color in chrome and safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, linear-gradients

I'm trying to render gradient and it's collor is different on safari and chrome. How to make it identical? (Left - chrome, right - safari).

https://codepen.io/max-frai/pen/XWMEQZJ

```
<div id="test"></div>
#test {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(102,182,252,0) 0%,rgba(63,82,111,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(102,182,252,0) 0%,rgba(63,82,111,1) 100%);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/38391457/483779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a good explanation of what is going on [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-images-3/#premultiplied).  Basically, this has been in the working draft for years now, and Safari is the only major player who hasn't fixed it.  See current status [here](https://caniuse.com/css-gradients):

> Partial support in Safari and Older Firefox versions refers to not
> using premultiplied colors which results in unexpected behavior when
> using the transparent keyword as advised by the spec.

I guess if you were desperate, you could calculate the gradient yourself and put in a lot of stop points.  Otherwise just wait for Apple to fix.